# Traefik rewrite path

Tags: traefik

I have a document at `my.host.com/foo/bar/docpath`, and I want it to be available at the url `my.host.com/docpath`. All my Traefik config is in a docker-compose file.

This is the config in my service's container :

```
labels:
      traefik.enable: "true"
      traefik.http.routers.myservice.entrypoints: secure
      traefik.http.routers.myservice.middlewares: rewritepath
      traefik.http.routers.myservice.rule: "Host(`my.host.com`) && Path(`/docpath`)"
```

and in the Traefik's container labels :

```
labels:
      traefik.http.middlewares.rewritepath.addprefix.prefix: /foo/bar
```

Problem : when I request `my.host.com/docpath`, I have a 404 error. What do I do wrong ?

(given that I access correctly to `my.host.com/foo/bar/docpath` with a simple rule: "Host(`my.host.com`)" and no middleware)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding of traefik is, that middlewares are called after rules.

Try this.

```
  - "traefik.http.routers.myservice.rule: "Host(`my.host.com`) && Path(`/docpath`)"
  - "traefik.http.routers.myservice.middlewares=rewritepath"
  - "traefik.http.middlewares.rewritepath.addprefix.prefix=/foo/bar"
```

Comment: That's it, the middleware definition just needed to be in the same container config. Many thanks !

Comment: This is indeed not very clear in Traefik's docs when labels should be put in the Traefik's service or in other services' definitions. I struggled with it too. I actually wrote a tuto about how to set up several Traefik options, maybe it will help you for other questions you'll have: https://juliensalinas.com/en/traefik-reverse-proxy-docker-compose-docker-swarm-nlpcloud/